# How to use regular expression in python to get integer value from a String with metacharacters

Tags: python-2.7, html-parsing

I have used beautiful soup to scrap data from a live web page.I have a variable price which is in "$" and i want to extract only the integer part of it.So i have used regular expression as follows :

```
    price = soup.find('span',{"class":"price"})
    prices =re.search(r'[\d{1,}]+', price.text.strip()).group()
```

The problem is, the prices is a string and when i use int(prices) it gives an error as follows:

## ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,400'

Comment: you can remove `,` from string and then do int(string) ?

Comment: it worked and thank you